# Twin log regression where result has a divison form

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am experimenting with regression. I am trying to replicate a log problem.

If I have a model that can be written as

$ Y = aX_{1}^{b1}X_{2}^{b2},...,X_{n}^{bn}$

and by taking the log of both sides:

$log(Y) = log_{10}(a) + b_{1}log_{10}X_{1} + b_{2}log_{10}X_{2}+ ... + b_{n}log_{10}X_{n}$

then results in the linear form of

$ Y = a + b_{1}X_{1} + b_{2}X_{2} + ... + b_{n}X_{n} $

However, the problem I am looking to recreate the results of a log-log regression, from which a resulting model is in a division form (example shown below).

$ Y = \frac{X_{1}^{b1}.X_{2}^{b2}}{X_{3}^{b3}} $

If I was to run this into the Statsmodels, I would use the liner form. Therefore, I assume I just convert the dependent and independent variables by $log_{10}$. The to achieve the denominator, I take the inverse of B ($\frac{1}{X_{3}^{b3}}$) to achieve that regression form?

Comment: This is just very unclear. What is $A$ why exponent $2.3$, what is $B$ why exponent $4.1$? Is this a model? are they constants, functions into which data enter etc. Please try to clarify (not here in comments but by editing the original question).

Comment: Is that any better? Basically, I am a little confused how they used the twin log regression and resulted in a model that is in a division form?

Comment: If you take the log of $y = x_1^{b_1} x_2^{b_2}/x_3^{b_2}$ you get $\log y = b_1\log x_1 + b_2 \log x_2 - b_3 \log x_3$ if you have data on $(y,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ parameters $b_1,b_2,b_3$ can be estimated by regression under certain well known assumptions. And this would require transforming variable $(y_1,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ into the corresponding logged-variables and using these transformed variables in the regression. But I am a litlle confused whether this what you are uncertain about!?

Comment: Yes it is.  it was the $-b_{3}logX_{3}$ I was uncertain about. Thanks for the clarification.